# Input with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here's my principal script code

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import commands
import config
import sys

# Coloroma autoreset
init(autoreset=True)


def check_database():
        # Database Check.
        while True:
            db = input("Check for new databases? Y/N: ")
            if db.lower() == 'y':
                commands.db_download()
                break
            elif db.lower() == 'n':
                break
            else:
                continue

def client_use():
    # Decide which client to use.
    while True:
        client = input("JP or GLB? J/G: ")
        if client.lower() == 'j':
            config.client = 'japan'
            break
        elif client.lower() == 'g':
            config.client = 'global'
            break
        else:
            continue
```

I want at the launch of the gui for example a button with "Launch bot" (that i managed to do) and right after my script above starts. Like it asks "Check for new db?" and i have two buttons "Yes" or "No" and depending on what i click, it sends an input with "y" or "n" and it continues the corresponding code lines.That point i didnt manage to do.

And here's what i managed to do for now, which isn't much at all

```py
import tkinter
import questions


top = tkinter.Tk()

Lancement = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Lancer", command = questions)
Lancement.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

How could i manage to do that plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter comes with some additional dialog boxes for asking questions (see https://pythonspot.com/tkinter-askquestion-dialog/)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def launch():
    response = messagebox.askyesno("Server Connection", "Check for new db?")
    if response:
        print("You clicked yes")
    else:
        print("You clicked no")


root = Tk()
button = Button(root,text="Launch",command=launch)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Clicking on the launch button will bring up a dialog with yes/no buttons.

You will need to re-structure your code to accept the responses from these dialogs rather than the command line text input functions.

Comment: You mean that i'll have to change it in my principal script? Like the "db = input("Check for new databases? Y/N: ") " I'll have to change that?

Comment: @Ace Yes. You'll need to change your 'principal' script.

Comment: but how can i change it the way it get the same results.. I needed it to be like it cuz of the way it has to work, so im a little bit lost now :(

Comment: @Ace. Short answer is you can't. You can't have both a command line entry AND a tkinter dialog. Also you can't have a `while true` loop inside a tkinter program. You can still achieve the same result but you will have to refactor your existing code.